# How to set and retrieve the global variable's values in the feature file in karate?

Tags: karate

I am new to this Karate framework. I want to set the user creation ID into a global variable from user creation feature file and I want to use the same in another feature file. I read some documentation but it didn't help me to succeed.

I tried karate-config.js file to create variable and tried to use that in the feature file. But didn't work.

```
  var config = {
    env: env,
    baseUrl: 'http://**************',
    pds5_id: 'empty',
    pds5_token: 'empty'
  } 

Given path 'pds','identities' 
  And request {}
 When method post
 Then status 200
  And def pds_id = response.id
  And set pds5_id = pds_id
```

I expected to save this user id into the global variable "pds5_id" but getting the below error

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: create_identities.feature:16 - cannot set json path on unexpected type: [type: STRING, value: empty]
    at ✽.And set pds5_id = pds_id (create_identities.feature:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a variable is set in `karate-config.js` you cannot change it, so this is wrong (and `set` only works on JSON with a path expression):

```
And set pds5_id = pds_id
```

What you need to read is this part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

Take a deep breath and read it carefully, the time will be worth it. And you will find the answer.

Keep in mind that having one `Scenario` depend on another is wrong: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure - so don't think in terms of "global" variables - just use a re-usable feature wherever needed.

If you really have a need to have a one-time variable set at the start, that is what `callSingle()` is for: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks - but first try to get the basics working since you are new to Karate.

Comment: Hi, @Peter. Thanks for the answer. To my understanding, the sign feature will run again if we use 'call' option. "def signIn = call read('classpath:my-signin.feature')". In my project, a signed in token is valid for 30 minutes and i don't want to run this again and again. Also for the user id scenario, we can't call again and again to get the user id because if we call the scenario for the second time, the UAT will throw an error message as duplicate user creation.

Comment: @RajkamalS. then please look at `callSingle()` as I already suggested

Comment: Yes @Peter, I read about an option **"karate.callSingle(fileName, [arg])"** but most of my project positive cases will return the id or tokens. so, how to use this callSingle for all the positive cases?

Comment: @RajkamalS. for the last time - please read the docs and examples. use `callSingle()` in karate-config.js - and you will get a token that you can use in all your positive cases. if this answer does not help, maybe karate is too complicated for you - so please use another framework

Comment: Please, Suggest me some good practice to be followed like we are using properties file used in java. Currently, we are using the rest-assured with JAVA & CUCUMBER for this same project.

Comment: @RajkamalS. that is a completely different question - so ask another question if required. but my observation is you have not understood why Karate is designed to get you away from properties files and Java itself - so unless you read the documentation (which you clearly have not) - I advise you to look at other options, or continue to use rest-assured. all the best !

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will read the documentation clearly.